# How to provide access only to current logged in user in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-contextual-filters

I am building a site in Drupal.

I have a contextual url user/%/posts which gives me a view
Suppose there are two users with uid 1 and 2

uid 1 should be able to access access only user/1/posts and not user/2/posts
Similarly with uid 2

How to do this in Drupal ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both Views and Views PHP enabled :

1. Go to your view's admin page.
2. Click on Page settings > Access and select the PHP option.
3. Check if the current logged-in user (uid) matches the uid argument from the URL.

`<?php global $user; return ($user->uid == $view->args[0]); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
global $user;
return ($user->uid == 1 || $user->uid == $argument);
```

for content owner & UID1 access  (https://www.drupal.org/node/2325229#comment-9130871)